# How to wrap alt tags XHTML 1.0 strict

Tags: css, image, xhtml

I'm trying to ensure my alt description displays within the confines of the image - this will appear when email clients are image blocking. The issue I have is that my image is 75x75px and therefore not very large.

If I only write a couple of words this displays no problem, however I want to write 9 words, which is clearly too long and has the consequence of all text disappearing completely.

It seems like some sort of a wrap or no-break command would be required but I've tried so many variations and been pulling my hair out over this for more time than I should admit so any help greatly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
        <title>My signature</title>
        <style type="text/css">

            /*////// RESET STYLES //////*/
            table{border-collapse:collapse;}
            img, a img{border:0; outline:none; text-decoration:none;}
            img{white-space:pre}
            .applelinks a {color:#999; text-decoration: none;}
        </style>
    </head>


    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <p style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px;">
                        <a href="http://www.website.com" class="clink">
                        <img style="border: 0px none; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; color: #00d1b6; font-style: italic; font-weight: bold; height: 75px; width: 75px;" alt="The text I put here is so long it disappears altogether" src="image-75x75.gif" width="75" height="75"/>
                        </a>
                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is no way to provide better handling of alt text in rubbish clients.

Comment: Thanks. In that case do you know if it's possible to prevent the missing image box and icon from appearing?  Or, if I understand correctly, can I and how can serve a multipart/ alternate signature?